# multiplying conv layer weights( N,C,H,W) with Logits (H,W) pytorch

Tags: pytorch, feature-extraction, logits

I am implementing the paper [Deep multiscale convolutional feature learning for weakly supervised localization of chest pathologies in X-ray images](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.08280.pdf)
According to my understanding the layer relevance weights belong to the last layer of each dense block.

I tried implementing the weight constraints as shown below:

```
 def weight_constraints(self):

        weights= {'feat1': self.model.features.denseblock2.denselayer12.conv2.weight.data,
            'feat2':self.model.features.denseblock3.denselayer24.conv2.weight.data,
            'feat3':self.model.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.conv2.weight.data}

        sum(weights.values()) == 1

        for i in weights.keys():
            w = weights[i]    
            w1 = w.clamp(min= 0)
            weights[i] = w1
        return weights


 weights= self.weight_constraints()
        for i in weights.keys():
            w = weights[i]
            l = logits[i]
            p = torch.matmul(w , l[0])
            sum = sum + p
```

where logits is a dictionary which contains out of FC layer from each block as shown in the diagram.

> logits = {'feat1': [tensor([[-0.0630]], ...ackward0>)], 'feat2': [tensor([[-0.0323]], ...ackward0>)], 'feat3': [tensor([[-8.2897e-06...ackward0>)]}

I get the following error :

> mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (12288x3 and 1x1)

Is this the right approach?

Comment: Isn't the logit dimension `(H, W, C)`, if `C` is the number of classes?

Comment: for now i am treating it as a binary classification problem(normal vs abnormal), with output node = 1 for FC layers of each block

Comment: In my understanding for binary classification you should have two classes at the output (logits).

Comment: understood, but as you can see in the paper, binary cross entropy loss is used which requires one output logit. please correct me if im wrong

Comment: Cross entropy uses one logit per class, check documentation for pytorch CrossEntropy [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html)

Comment: but the loss formula mentioned in paper seems to be BCE loss as mentioned [here.](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html#torch.nn.BCELoss). which takes one output from FC and moreover, Sigmoid is used for BC  where as Softmax is used for MC classification with CE loss as mentioned in [this](https://medium.com/dejunhuang/learning-day-57-practical-5-loss-function-crossentropyloss-vs-bceloss-in-pytorch-softmax-vs-bd866c8a0d23) 
My main question here is, in the paper BCE loss is implemented with Sigmoid, so how can **w.shape[-1] == l.shape[-1] (presumably 3).** be 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

The paper states

> The
> logit response from all the layers have same dimension (equal to the number of
> category for classification) and now can be combined using class specific [convex
> combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) to obtain the probability score for the class pc.

The function [matmul](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html) you used perfroms matrix multiplications, it requires `mat1.shape[-1] == mat2.shape[-2]`.

If you assume `sum(w)==1`, and `torch.all(w > 0)`, you could compute the convex combination of `l` as `(w * l).sum(-1)` that is multiply `w` and `l` element-wise, broadcasting over the batch dimensions of `l`, and requiring `w.shape[-1] == l.shape[-1]` (presumably 3).

If you want to stick with matmul you can add one dimension to `w` and `l`, and perform the vector product as a matrix multiplication: `torch.matmul(w[...,None,:], l[..., :, None])`.

Comment: thank you!. i want output to be of dimension [C,1] so that i can pass it into sigmoid. In my case, C= 1. My weights dimension is [32,128,3,3] and my logits dimension is [1,1]. in your mentioned solution i get output of dimension [32,128,3,3].

Comment: this formula worked when i changed weights shape to **w = weights.view(logits.size(0),-1)**